# I cannot correctly use Doctrine repository

Tags: php, symfony, pdo, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Ok, I know that title may be too general, but I will try to describe it better here.

I'm learning Symfony (totally rookie with Symfony), And I'm trying to make my first POST endpoint with store value to database. Everything is working for now except persisting data to db.

I create Entity Account.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Account\Infrastructure\Repository\Doctrine\DoctrineAccountRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="accounts", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="accounts_id", columns={"id"})})
 */
class Account
{
    use UniqueIdentifierTrait;

    /**
     * @var \App\Account\Infrastructure\Entity\Doctrine\Email
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Account\Infrastructure\Entity\Doctrine\Email", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, unique=true, onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private Email $email;

    /**
     * @var \App\Account\Infrastructure\Entity\Doctrine\Credentials
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Account\Infrastructure\Entity\Doctrine\Credentials", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, unique=true, onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private Credentials $credentials;

    /**
     * @param \App\Account\Core\ValueObject\Uuid $id
     * @param \App\Account\Infrastructure\Entity\Doctrine\Email $email
     * @param \App\Account\Infrastructure\Entity\Doctrine\Credentials $credentials
     */
    public function __construct(Uuid $id, Email $email, Credentials $credentials)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->credentials = $credentials;
    }
}
```

And I have also repository for it

```
class DoctrineAccountRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    /**
     * @param \App\Account\Infrastructure\Entity\Doctrine\Account $account
     * @return void
     * @throws \App\Internal\Infrastructure\Exception\SaveException
     */
    public function save(Account $account): void
    {
        try {
            $this->getEntityManager()->persist($account);

            $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
        } catch (ORMException $e) {
            throw new SaveException($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

And I have Service Configuration:

```
services:
  _defaults:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true

  App\Account\Infrastructure\Repository\Doctrine\DoctrineAccountRepository:
    arguments:
      - '@Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry'
      - App\Account\Infrastructure\Entity\Doctrine\Account
```

I think that I bind it correctly, but due to shooting the request in Postman, I get
`PDOException: could not find driver.` The exception is thrown due `$em->flush()`;

This is strange for me because my migrations are executed sucessfully, so app makes the connection with database.

Doctrine config

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_DRIVER)%' # <-- pdo_sqlsrv
        host: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_HOST)%'
        port: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_PORT)%'
        user: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_USER)%'
        password: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_PASSWORD)%'
        dbname: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_NAME)%'
        charset: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_CHARSET)%'

``
```

Comment: Check if you really have correctly loaded pdo_sqlsrv driver. Migrations doesn't need PDO driver I guess. Create empty PHP file with some minimal working example to test PDO driver if it really works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Migrations usually run from command line, while web requests run via php-fpm or some cgi module, both of which might have a very different php.ini file they load, thus allowing the situation where php cli works nicely due to loaded drivers while server requests fail due to missing drivers. the fix obviously is to enable the drivers in the relevant php ini file.

`phpinfo()` (in php obviously) will mention the loaded ini file(s) somewhere at the top. for example on my server the output might be (request):

[image: server output]

while the cli outputs:

[image: cli output]

Comment: Ok, I didn't have correctly installed sqlsrv extension. I don't want to play with that, so I changed the driver on pdo_mysql